# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application with Gradle example

Tags: gradle, javafx

I know this has been asked multiple times... but I can't seem to find a solution.

Taken from this official guidelines example: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle
I went on and added in my **build.gradle** :

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

javafx {
    version = '13'
    modules = ['javafx.controls']
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = "MyImage"

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

which, by running **gradle jar** (or **gradle build**), should actually produce a jar which should include all the packages it builds it with, that is the entire javafx library.

However, when it builds successfully and then I proceed with running:

`java -jar build/libs/MyImage.jar`

it still throws the error:

`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

What am I missing?

(I use JDK 11)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 11 the Java launcher detects that you're extending javafx.application.Application and checks the modules are present. If you're using plain old JARs then you'll get the error

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

You have two choices. Setup your application to use the Java module system or the following workaround.

This workaround avoids the Java launcher check and will let the application run.

```
public class MyImage {   // <=== note - does not extend Application

    public static class YourRealApplication extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            // whatever...
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(YourRealApplication.class);
    }

}
```